# PHP Script not Fetching Data From Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database with the field `Unique ID`, which has two rows in it, both integers. The first row has value `3` and the second row `4`. The aim of this script is to find the one with the highest value, but it only `echo`'s "Unique ID".

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root");

if(!$connection) {
die("Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("rewiredstate",$connection);
$max="SELECT MAX('Unique ID') as id FROM topics";
$maxquery= mysql_query($max) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($maxquery)) {
echo $row['id'];
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be wrong with it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but if this is new code I suggest you look into [`mysqli`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), because the `mysql_` functions [will be deprecated soon](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need different quotes - ` rather than '

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around Unique ID like this:

```
$max="SELECT MAX(Unique ID) as id FROM topics";
```

The mistake in your query is that, you have used wrong quote around the field name in MAX function. As per your query, the MAX function is given a string as parameter, which it compares with no real field values in the table. Thats why it returns **Unique ID** in the result.

You need to use MAX(`field`) OR you can choose not to use quote at all, like MAX(field). But certainly not MAX('field').